# Yoneda-weighted limits

Tags: ct.category-theory

Consider a simplicial category $\cal D$, and a cosimplicial object $c\colon \Delta\to \cal D$. Let $y\colon \Delta\to \bf sSet$ denote the Yoneda embedding.

How do you characterize the limit of $c$  weighted by $y$ (provided it exists)?

**Partial answer**: Whatever it is such an object,its associated representable presheaf must behave in such a way that
$$
{\cal D}\big(d,\textstyle \text{lim}^yc\big)\cong {\bf Set}^{\Delta^\text{op}\times\Delta}\big( y,{\cal D}(d,c-) \big)
$$
or in other words
$$\begin{align*}
{\cal D}\big(d, \text{lim}^yc\big) &\cong {\bf Set}^{\Delta^\text{op}\times\Delta}\big( y,{\cal D}(d,c-) \big)\\
& \int_{n\in\Delta}{\bf sSet}\big( \Delta_n, {\cal D}(d, c_n) \big)\\
&\cong \int_{n\in\Delta} {\cal D}(d, c_n)_n
\end{align*}$$
which is the "cotrace" (?) of the profunctor $\Delta^\text{op}\times\Delta\to{\bf Sets}\colon (m,n)\mapsto {\cal D}(d, c_n)_m$. Is this something meaningful? How can it be generalized to the case of a functor $F\colon \cal C\to D$, where $\cal D$ is a $\widehat{\cal C}$-category?

Comment: I'm even more motivated now that I strongly suspect that the particular weighted limit I'm looking for is in some sense dual to the geometric realization of a simplicial set. Any idea is welcome!

Comment: It's called the "totalization" of your cosimplicial object and it is, indeed, dual to the geometric realization.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me a reference or answer in detail with some situations where such a thing appears?

Comment: There's a definition in 19.8.1 of Hirschorn's book on model categories, but it may not be very penetrable.  In the case D=sSet, it's mentioned in section VII.5 of Goerss+Jardine's book Simplicial Homotopy Theory.